# Bash - Export odp / ppt slides as images

Tags: bash, openoffice.org

Is it possible to export odp / ppt slides as images using **unoconv**?

For example,

> unoconv -f png presentation.ppt

But this unoconv command converts **only the first slide** as a png file. Is it possible to **export all slides as individual images**, say, 001.png, 002.png, 003.png using unoconv on the command line?

If not, could you suggest a simple bash script to go over slide by slide in the odp / ppt file to convert to images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to first convert it to PDF, and then use Ghostscript to convert to PNG files.  The following works for me:

```
unoconv -f pdf presentation.ppt
gs -sOutputFile=presentation-%03d.png -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=png16m \
   -dBATCH -q -r300 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 presentation.pdf
```

(The `-r300` parameter says to create 300 pixels-per-inch PNG files - you may want to adjust that.)

Comment: Sure, you can just change the `-sDEVICE` parameter to `-sDEVICE=jpeg` and remember to change the extension on the `-sOutputFile` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert the PPT file to HTML:

```
unoconv -o image/  -f html SinoProbe_02_02_001.ppt
```

Then the image folder will fill with HTML and JPG files.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the Export as Images extension for Open Office v4.1.1 on Windows 7. Worked GREAT.  I had more control over the graphics size etc than when exporting to HTML and using the included files.

http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/export-images